# Silverstripe: how can I debug a GraphQL Error?

Tags: debugging, graphql, silverstripe

In Silverstripe, GraphQL provides an error in the browser console, but there is no backtrace, making debugging tricky.  Is there a way to get a backtrace?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't turn any debugging on or something like that, but you can use the trick below.

To find out where the error occurs you add the backtrace call (as below), just before the location where the error occurs.

```php
use SilverStripe\Dev\Backtrace;

class Foo 
{
    function Bar()
    {
        // conditional to only catch error
        Backtrace::backtrace();

        // actual error is below
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using XDebug, setting a couple of breakpoints on code that you know gets executed or which you suspect may be related to the problem, and stepping through the code with the debugger running.